# debug numeric overflow issue in Oracle

Tags: string, oracle, debugging

In short out of ~8.2 million records I think there is one or two records that is causing a hiccup with this statement:

```
to_number(regexp_substr(meas_value, '\d+(\.\d+)?', 1, 1)) num1
```

I have parsed out the dataset into 45 smaller ones via a SAS macro running the Oracle query.
44 queries work, 1 does not.

For the life of me I don't know how to "debug" the query in Oracle that I can find the problem observation.  I am using Oracle SQL developer.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of "hiccup"? What is the exact error message?

Comment: I get a numeric overflow error

Comment: Maybe some of the numbers are too long, so they overflow the maximum integer value.

Comment: what would be the maximum integer value?

Comment: One of the values represents (or seems to represent) a numeric value that is [too large for the data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78). I'd suggest you start with getting the substring - maybe just the integer part, with `regexp_substr(meas_value, '\d+', 1, 1)` - and order by the length of that descending; that will give you the longest strings it's trying to convert. (This is why you shouldn't store numbers as strings... these seem to be part of a longer non-numeric string, but still...)

Comment: @Barmar-You mean something like this-'999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999'  -Thanks

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole. I think I found my culprit..

Comment: @LawrenceBlock - yes, [that would do it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9986360a0b5e582cb3ae3d259df71355).

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`validate_conversion`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD) function to filter such problematic values:

> ```
> with a (l, num) as (
>   select
>     level,
>     lpad('9', level*30, '9')
>   from dual
>   connect by level < 7
> )
> select *
> from a
> where validate_conversion(num as number) = 0
> ```
>
> ```
>  L | NUM                                                                                                                                                                                 
> -: | :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  5 | 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999                              
>  6 | 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c42ccf98a12a05c5eec326150680ce5c)*